# How to "paste" two files without writing to a new file?

Tags: awk, sed, paste

I am doing this

```
for pathname in /user/home/file_*; do
    cat "$pathname" | sed -n '3p'; printf"\n";
done> user/home/foo;

for pathname in /user/home/file_*; do
    cat "$pathname" | grep "word";
    printf"\n";
done> user/home/bar;

paste foo bar > combined
```

How can I write to `combined` directly without writing to `foo` & `bar`? Trying to reduce the runtime as the directory is huge

I tried

```
for pathname in /user/home/file_*; do
    cat "$pathname" | sed -n '3p'; printf"\n";
done | paste > combined;

for pathname in /user/home/file_*; do
    cat "$pathname" | grep "word";
    printf"\n";
done | paste > combined;
```

But it will overwrite the first list

Comment: It strikes me that the runtime may not be in creating the two temporary files and combining them, in two steps, but letting `sed` (in the first loop) read the entirety of the each file (and not only to line 3). You are also invoking `cat` needlessly for each file, twice.  Your use of `paste` also makes me wonder what you want the output to look like.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because we are never shown an example what the expected output should look like.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, may have misunderstood the question.
May be the same as
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31546680/how-to-pipe-grep-output-to-paste-input

The "paste" command takes 2 or more files rather than streams,
keeping the column structures and putting them left to right in the combined file.
For combining columns left to right, the following link
may be interesting:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/paste-command-in-linux-with-examples/
in the section "2. Combination with other commands" where they talk about combining with "cut".
If file1 has 2 columns separated by tabs; file2 has 1 column; you can do sequential pipes of cut and paste:

```
cut -d\      -f1-2 file1 | paste - file2 | cut -d\   -f1-3 | paste - file3
```

where the invisible character after -d\  is a tab (ctl-V tab on the command line, actually tab might be the default delimiter for "cut" as it is for "paste") and the hyphen after each "paste" is the position of the columns of the piped-in stream.

or like this, since all of the columns are kept :

```
cut -d\      -f1-2 file1 | paste - file2 | paste - file3
```

If you wanted all of the output from the 2nd file underneath the output from the 1st file
then the original suggestion with subshells

```
( source cmdLIST1.csh ; source cmdLIST2.csh ) > combinedOUTPUT.txt
```

might have worked.

Chai's answer seems to work in "bash" & "zsh" but not "tcsh" and is probably easiest.

Comment: Why did you delete your last phrases?

Answer (score 1):

One way can be a call to awk to ask it to print the 3rd line and/or word containing line. The output is merge-pasted 2 lines at a time and written to file named combined. Note this assumes word occurs once.

```
$ for pathname in /user/home/file_*; do
    awk '/word/;NR==3' < "$pathname" 
  done | paste  - - > combined
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$ paste <(for pathname in /user/home/file_*; do cat "$pathname" | sed -n '3p'; printf "\n"; done) <(for pathname in /user/home/file_*; do cat "$pathname" | grep "word"; printf "\n"; done)
```

But behind the scenes, the shell would be using some temp files, I am thinking.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for

```
for pathname in /user/home/file_*; do
    cat "$pathname" | sed -n '3p'; printf"\n";
done > user/home/combined

for pathname in /user/home/file_*; do
    cat "$pathname" | grep "word";
    printf"\n";
done >> user/home/combined
```

The first `>` will create the file and the second step will append to the file with `>>`.

Answer (score 0):

```bsh
for f in /user/home/file_*; do
    printf '%s\t%s\n' "$(sed -n '3{p;q;}' "$f")" "$(grep 'word' "$f")"
done > combined
```

In case the files are big, I've added a quit command to sed.